# How would I go about taking a snapshot of a portion of my application's window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently attempting to take snapshot of a specified portion of my application's window from a specified starting coordinate (which is where my problem comes in).

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle((this.Width/2)-400,(this.Height/2)-200, 800,400);

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{   
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
        PrintWindow(this.axS.Handle, hdc, 0);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        graphics.Flush();
        string file = "example.png";
        bitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to make a dynamic-adaptive method to take a screenshot of the center of the window, even after being resized. I'm not sure how to apply `x` and `y` to the screenshot as a starting point for the screenshot. Dimensions will always remain `800,400` and always taking a screenshot of the center of the application regardless of window size.

Every attempt I have pegged, the bitmap took a screenshot from `0 (+800), 0 (+400)` where `0, 0` I need to change.

Is `Bitmap` capable of this? If not, what other method could I use?

Comment: Can you fill in the `...` part that actually takes the screen shot into the `Bitmap`?  What you posted just creates an empty bitmap.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I didn't think that was really relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SetViewportOrgEx` to set the origin on the HDC.  I found that the title bar of the window was throwing off the calculation of the center point, so I took that into account as well.

```
int x = (this.Width / 2) - 400;
int y = ((this.Height + SystemInformation.CaptionHeight) / 2) - 200;

Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, 800, 400);

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
        POINT pt;

        SetViewportOrgEx(hdc, -x, -y, out pt);

        // rest as before
    }
}
```

And the signatures for `SetViewportOrgEx` and `POINT`:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern bool SetViewportOrgEx(IntPtr hdc, int X, int Y, out POINT lpPoint);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
    {
        return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
    }

    public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
    {
        return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adrift! Seems to be working perfectly. I don't necessarily understand /how/ it worked; something I'll look into later. :)

Comment: @Salt, you're welcome, and if you find your captures are not exactly centered, please see the updated code above to take the title bar height into account.

Comment: The center was a few 30 pixels off; I trial-and-error'd until I got it pixel-perfect. However, I strive for efficiency, so I'll make the necessary modifications. I sincerely appreciate your and Sam's effort in helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `PrintWindow` try using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` which allows you to specify both an upper-left corner as well as dimensions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yfzc507.aspx

> Performs a bit-block transfer of color data, corresponding to a rectangle of pixels, from the screen to the drawing surface of the Graphics.

`CopyFromScreen` works on screen coordinates so you'll have to calculate that for the call.

Comment: That would seem like a solution, however, the first thing that came to mind was multi-monitors; I'm unsure if that would be compatible or would be ensued by a multitude of problems. Is there any 'local' method (as `PrintWindow` does, utilizing only the application window)? I'm not entirely sure how I would get the coordinates on the screen. I assume it would involve a function to get the position of the window (also assuming the position returned would be an XY coordinate of the top-left corner of the application), and would have to compensate for the title bar and window border?